# Blender cycles - Diffuse + transparent map in one material

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency

So I'm trying to make a material by using two maps: diffuse and transparency map but I can't get these two maps to work together.

This is how my nodes and specific textures are looking.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4lZ0.jpg

I hope that the issue is perfectly visible. I just want to "cut off" this black part of flag to make it look like a torn fabric by using diff and trans like in PBR.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last node, that you need to plug into material output is a Mix node, that mix your material node(diffuse, principled ets) and transparent node using mask:

[image]

Full setup:

[image]

Next you can plug more complex material instead just diffuse node. For example, principled, just keep mix with transparent node at the end:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I think some time will pass when I'll finally understand how transparency is working in nodes but for now, thank you!